# How to make pipeline fail when a error is outputted from java appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, appium, lambdatest

I want to make my pipeline fail if I have an error.
For now, for example, if I don't find an item, my pipeline shows as if everything is OK.

For example, if i dont obtain an element, i say to my code that do this lines:

```
driver.executeScript("lambda-status=failed");
driver.quit();
```

the first one is to show in lambda test like my test is failed, and de second one is to finish the test.

There is another way to quit the driver?, something like. driver.quit("error"); or something like that.
I want to do this to my pipeline fails if exist any error in my test.